Show updated content with a ServerSocket
I'm trying to add a web server to my Android app. What I have works the first time the user visits the server but if they refresh, how I can I show them updated content if they refresh the page?
new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
        serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(8080));

        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

        out.write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
        out.write("Content-Length: 59\r\n");
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.write("<html>");
        out.write("<style>");
        out.write("body{margin: 12px;}");
        out.write("</style>");
        out.write("<title>Web Server</title>");
        //output dynamic data
        out.write("</html>");

        out.close();
        clientSocket.close();


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}).start();


If the user refreshes the browser will connect again and you can sent new content.

In above code you are not closing the serversocket.

A few things:
1)Android is NOT a good server OS.  Services are killed quickly if the app isn't in the foreground.  It is not recommended to run an HTTP server on Android.  Down this road is a lot of pain.
2)That's not how HTTP works.  You don't get updates-  HTTP is one time request and return.  If you want to do that, you either need to poll refreshing the page, you need to create a web endpoint, poll it, and use it to fetch data and build the page yourself in javascript, or you need to use a websocket to do the same thing as option 2.  Neither of them are as simple as just building an HTTP server.

Well, it's for a media app so I already have a foreground service running. I think I can get around the issue of refreshing the page because everything works except that. Thanks for the response.
